# how to append element to a QList in a structure?

Tags: qt, struct, append, qlist

I have a struct like this one :

```
struct Nom {  
    QString Nom;  
    ....  
    QList<quint64> indNum;  
}
```

In my .h file. I declare :
QVector *n;

In my .cpp file. I declare :

```
n = new QVector<Nom>;
```

I read a file to fill in *n*.
When I write this :

```
n->back().indNum.append(i->size()-1);
```

it works.
When I write that :

```
n->at(j).indNum.append(i->size()-1);
```

I have a compilation error:

> no matching member funtion for call to 'append'
>   candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const 
>   QList', but method is not marked 
>   const void append(const T &t);

I don't understand why it works in the first case and the second.
Could anyone explain and help me solve this ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QVector::at` returns a const reference to the `Nom` value, so you cannot modify the item returned by `n->at(j)`. To get a non-const reference you can use `(*n)[j]`.

`n->back()` works because for `QVector::back` there is a const and a non-const overload.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I replace  'n->at(j)' by 'n[j]', I get another compilation : erreur : no member named 'indNum' in 'QVector<MainWindow::Nom>'
                      n[j].indNum.append(i->size()-1);
                      ~~~~ ^

Comment: Indeed. I don't have any compilation error now. Thanks a lot.